# Configuring fluentd to collect logs in Kubernetes from spring-boot applications

Tags: spring, kubernetes, logstash, fluentd

I have this logback setup in spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

   <appender class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" name="CONSOLE">
     <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
   </appender>

   <root level="INFO">
     <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
   </root>

</configuration>
```

How can I configure fluentd to collect logs from my spring applications in k8s and send them to elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to be more specific. What have you tried? What does not work as expected? ... collecting logs of a spring application with fluentd is not different to using any other technology, as long as is it streamed to stdout/stderr.

It should be pretty straight forward. See this: https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/how-to-deploy-an-efk-stack-to-kubernetes-ebc1b539d063 or https://devopscube.com/setup-efk-stack-on-kubernetes/

Comment: I requested many different fluentd configurations, but none of them collected logs from spring applications properly.

I expect logstash log to send object to elasticsearch {"@timestamp":"2022-07-13T14:25:31.739Z","@version":"1","message":"123","logger_name" :"com.suppy.logging.web.ExtRequestLoggingConfiguration$extRequestLoggingFilterReg$erlf$1","thread_name":"XNIO-1 task-1","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"traceId":" 03bc4ff653b623da","spanId":"03bc4ff653b623da"} and then I could see it in kibana and filter by any parameter of this json

Comment: Again, you have to be more specific in order get proper help. What exactly have you tried?. Then as there are multiple components involved you have to check where it does not work correctly. I am a little bit confused about the fact that you mix up fluentd and logstash. You should not use both I guess. Either fluentd or logstash. That is why people talk either of the EFK or ELK stack.

Comment: I don't want to merge logstash and fluentd. My spring applications generate logstash (logback) format, I want fluentd to collect logs from them in kubernetes and send them to elasticsearch. I will not be able to provide what configuration options that I have already tried.